# Android Как запретить менять стиль TextView с помощью системных настроек?

Tags: android, textview, text, style, android-style

В настройках системы -> дополнительные возможности - есть возможность включить контрастный текст (High contrast), который в итоге меняет стиль всего текста во всех приложениях. Что если мы хотим, чтобы наш дизайн оставался всегда не тронутым?

[image: Красота (нет)]

Например, в тех же настройках пользователь может включить увеличенный размер шрифта, можем запретить в нашем приложении использование больших шрифтов, если будем использовать dp вместо sp. Но как запретить использовать контраст?

Те крупицы, что удалось найти мало чем могут помочь:

[Enabling 'High Contrast Text' mode from within Android/Java using AccessibilityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402880/enabling-high-contrast-text-mode-from-within-android-java-using-accessibilitym)

[Detect if 'High contrast' is enabled in Android accessibility settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411712/detect-if-high-contrast-is-enabled-in-android-accessibility-settings)

Comment: У вас какая то личная неприязнь к людям с проблемами зрения? Зачем вы хотите, чтобы они испытывали проблемы с вашим приложением

Comment: @pavloff ожидал такой вопрос... конечно у меня нет неприязни, и уж точно я не желаю никому проблем с моим приложением. Вы же понимаете, мы люди подневольные, это одно из требований к проекту.